# post_detail() view missing required positional arguments:

Tags: python, django

I'm beginner to django . I am facing this problem that I can't get the post detail view with year , month and post .
Error is `post_detail()` missing 4 required positional arguments: 'year', 'month', 'day', and 'post'.

this is models.py

```
 from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


    class Post(models.Model):
        STAUTS_CHOICE = ( ('draft','Draft'),('published','Published'),)
        title =models.CharField(max_length =250) 
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length =250)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='blog_post')
        body = models.TextField()
        publish =models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        udated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
        status = models.CharField(max_length =250 , 
        choices = STAUTS_CHOICE , default = 'draft')

        class Meta:
             ordering = ('-publish',)               

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('blog:post_detail', args = [self.slug, self.publish.year , self.publish.strftime('%m'), self.publish.strftime('%d')]])  

        def __str__(self):
             return self.title
    ______________________________________________________________
```

this is  views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404 
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'post':post})

def post_detail(request,slug,year, month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug , status = 'published' ,publish_year = year, publish_month = month , publish_day = day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post':post})
```

---

this is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from .import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^post_list',views.post_list,name ='post_list'),
        url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
```

this is post_detail.html page

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}Post details{% endblock %} 
     {% block content %}
    <h2><a>{{post.title}}</a></h2>
    <p class="date">published {{ post.published}} by {{ post.author}}</p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
     {% endblock %}
```

this is list.html page :

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %} {% block head_title %}Posts list{% endblock %} 
{% block content %}
<h1>My Blog</h1>
{% for x in posts %}
<h2>
    <a href="{{ x.get_absolute_url }}">{{x.title}}</a>
</h2>
<p class="date">published {{ x.published}} by {{ x.author}}</p>
{{ x.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }} {% endfor %} {% endblock %}
```

this is base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>{% block head_title %}Welcome to my blog{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post your html where you have a <a tag> for the detail page in listing page

Comment: added it . please check it out.

Comment: add the list.html too

Comment: What is `post` that you are passing to `post_detail` view ?

Comment: added it -@Exprator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I guessed you want to resolve `domain/year/month/day/slug` URL.

The following changes will make it work.

views.py

```
def post_detail(request,slug,year, month,day):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug , status = 'published' ,publish__year = year, publish__month = month , publish__day = day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post':post})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^post_list',views.post_list,name ='post_list'),
        url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks , But I want to know what is the use of Post parameter in post_detail view ,

Answer (score 0):

remove post parameter from post_detail view. and remove third url for same view. Now your requested url should be:

```
localhost:8000/2017/12/16/my-post
```